# In the quadrilateral $ABCD$, find the measure of length $AB$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

As title suggests, in the following quadrilaterals with some given angles and lengths, the goal is to find the measure of the base length $AB$. This is a contest-preparation problem with several different ways to solve it. I'll post my own approach below as an answer, please share your solutions as well!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your approach is the best but as a suggestion:

Draw a line from $D$ parallel to $CB$ that intersects $AB$ at $F$. Since $DF$ is parallel to $CB$ and $\angle ADC =150 ^{\circ}$ we conclude that $DF=AF=48$. Now, draw a line from $F$ parallel to $DC$ intersecting $BC$ at $G$. Since $DF=48$ it is obtained that $BG=60-48=12$, and hence $BF=24$. Therefore $x=AF+BF=72$.

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach to this problem:

[image]

Extend $BC$ and $AD$ such that they intersect at point $E$. Since $\angle ECD=90$ and $\angle EDC=30$, we can conclude that $\angle AEB=60$, $\triangle AEB$ is equilateral and $\triangle CED$ is a $30-60-90$ triangle. Let $DE=2a$, this means that $CE=a$. Since $\triangle AEB$ is equilateral we can say that:

$$48+2a=60+a$$

$$a=12$$

Therefore, $x=60+a=60+12=72$

Comment: Note that you can deduce angle AEB is 60 without considering angle ADC, since the sum of the angles of triangle AEB must be 180.

Comment: True. In hindsight I probably could've done that and shortened the proof a bit. Thanks for the suggestion!